# Remove key value pairs

Tags: c#, wpf

I have class library which is already developed and in it the following code has been written,

```
public static PersistenceManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new PersistenceManager();
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }
```

where PersistenceManager is a class. I have a WPF application in which i am calling this dll and just before showing login page there is a code written as below,

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PersistenceManager.Instance["user"]))
            {
                StartupUri = new Uri("Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                StartupUri = new Uri("Messenger.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
```

I have already registered so it always shows messanger window. Now i want to clear the keyvalue of user so that i can show the login page. I am unable to perform below code ,

PersistenceManager.Instance["user"] = string.Empty;

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred

Any suggesions?

Index-Operator looks like:

```
  public string this[string key] 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            return _settingsDictionary[key].Decrypt(ENCKEY); 
        } 
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            return string.Empty; 
        } 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)) 
            _settingsDictionary[key] = value.Encrypt(ENCKEY); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does the Index-Operator in your PersistenceManager looks like?

Comment: public string this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return _settingsDictionary[key].Decrypt(ENCKEY);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                _settingsDictionary[key] = value.Encrypt(ENCKEY);
            }
        }

Comment: Could it be that your Encrypt-Method has an error?

Comment: @Sangeetha: The code that you have added in your comment is very relevant to your question so I suggest that you edit your question to incorporate the code. When your code throws an exception you should look at the stack trace to see the origin of the exception. In your case my guess is that it is the `Encrypt` extension method that throws the exception when you provide an empty string as the value to encrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite the index operator as following:

```
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {

            string value;
            _settingsDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;
            return value.Decrypt(ENCKEY);
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) _settingsDictionary.Remove(key);
            else _settingsDictionary[key] = value.Encrypt(ENCKEY);
        }
    }
```